# Download Document from Blob

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I can successfully upload a document in mysql blob (msword or pdf). Now I need help in downloading it.

**Here is My download button code.**

```
<form id="specificationdownload">
        <input type="hidden" name="cusid" id="cusid" value = "<?php echo $row['id_stk']?>">
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="downloadspec" type="submit">Download </button>
</form>
```

**Here is my Ajax code which handles the download button form**

```
//Specification download 
 $("form#specificationdownload").on("submit",function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
     jQuery.ajax({
     url: "../data/stock.php?action=stock-specification-download",
     type: "POST",           
     data: new FormData(this), 
     processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
    console.log(2);
    var filter = "<?php echo $id_stc ?>";
    var tab_content_to_change = "#stock-sub-list";
    jQuery(tab_content_to_change).load('/tasks/stock/stock-list.php?filter='+filter);
  },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    //Display error message to user
    alert("An error occured when saving the data");
  }
 });
 });
```

**Here is my action**

```
     $CustomerID = $_POST['cusid'];

    if(isset( $CustomerID )) 
    {

     //Query
    $prepare_query = "SELECT specificationsheet_name_stk,specificationsheet_type_stk,specificationsheet_size_stk, specificationsheet_stk FROM stock_stk 
    WHERE id_stk ='$CustomerID';";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_scs, $prepare_query);

    $row =  mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
    //die(var_dump($row));

    header("Content-length:" .$row['specificationsheet_size_stk']);
    header("Content-type:" .$row['specificationsheet_type_stk']);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['specificationsheet_name_stk']);
    return $row['specificationsheet_stk'];
    exit;
    }
```

The problem is when I click "Download" button, the file does not get downloaded. If I `var_Dump` the `$row`, It dump the array with right keys so object is there, but does not print.

Anybody know What I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: "Anybody know What I'm doing wrong." Yes abusing the database as a file system.... it's never a good idea to store files within a database.

Comment: I'ts stored in database for security reasons.